# Need to replace date functions in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, query-performance

We have a report functionality which uses scalar functions to pull the report. I tune it to an extent by converting functions to a stored procedure and applying best practices. 
I found we use date related functions in where clause which are not sargable due to following kind of conditons

```
AND dbo.mefn_GetDateDifference(c.date_of_birth,GETDATE(),'YEAR')  >=66
```

The function dbo.mefn_GetDateDifference is a classic example of calculating age where we first compare years and then month to give result set.

As I am using c.date_of_birth inside function, index on date_of_birth is not getting used.
Is anyone have better idea to optimize this?

Suppose one of my customers birthdate is '1939-05-20 00:00:00.000'
If we say

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year,'1939-05-20 00:00:00.000',GETDATE())
```

it gives me 75 years

But the function dbo.mefn_GetDateDifference calculates it to 74 as per following logic

```
DECLARE
    @adStartDate datetime,
    @adEndDate datetime,
    @asDateDifferenceType as varchar(20)

SET  @adStartDate='1939-05-20 00:00:00.000'
SET  @adEndDate=getdate()


DECLARE @iDateDifference int

set @iDateDifference = 0

 select @iDateDifference =   CASE when month(@adEndDate) > month(@adStartDate)  THEN DateDiff(year, @adStartDate, @adEndDate)   
                              when month(@adStartDate) = month(@adEndDate) and day(@adEndDate) >= day(@adStartDate) THEN DateDiff(year, @adStartDate, @adEndDate)   
                              ELSE DateDiff(year, @adStartDate, @adEndDate) - 1 END  



PRINT @iDateDifference
```

So due to this kind of discrepancy I am using function but for better performance I do not want to use it

Comment: `WHERE c.date_of_birth >= DATEADD(year, -66, GETDATE())`?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `> DATEADD(year, -67, GETDATE())` to include everyone up to *the day before their 67th birthday*.

Comment: If do you really need that column can you create a computed column to be able to get that value without recalculating it every time?

Comment: @jean, I always thought the main argument for a computed column is that it is recalculated every time.

Comment: @adrianm, not if the computed column is persisted in that case the value is stored and recalculated if the date_of_birth is updated only http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Depending on your business case (and the implementation details of the function), you may still need to use your function anyways.  Of course, being able to specify a simple search condition would allow the optimizer to cut down on the number of rows it calls the function on.  SQL Server already has a `DATEDIFF(...)` function, so I'm a little worried about what that thing is doing...  @MatBailie - I think you have that condition backwards, and he seems to be looking for people **older** than 65 years of age; `date_of_birth < DATEADD(year, -66, GETDATE())`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you first create a variable with the currentdate minus 67 or 66, and then work with that variable in your where clause?

```
DECLARE @CalculateDate DATETIME
SET @CalculateDate = DATEADD(year, -66, GETDATE())

SELECT * 
FROM (....)
WHERE date_of_birth <= @CalculateDate
```

Edit: Response to ADK
The value of @CalculateDate is now Mar 11 1948  8:58AM
In your example I can see why you use a custom function, but in my example this isn't necessary I think.

When we calculate with the date itself, we do not have to calculate the 'birthday years' anymore, cause whe've already got the right date itself, from where we can calculate if someone is 66 or older.

Comment: ... as opposed to just putting the `DATEADD(...)` expression in the `WHERE` clause?  The big problem is getting `date_of_birth` out of the function and into a straight comparison, not calculating it outside of the statement itself.

Comment: @GercoOnline - Could you please check the part I have edited few moments back.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, the problem you're facing is that the system has to go over each and every record to calculate `dbo.mefn_GetDateDifference(c.date_of_birth,GETDATE(),'YEAR')` in order to find out if matches or not. Although there are situations where you could try to put the formula in a calculated field and have it pre-calculated by putting an index on it; this won't be possible here as the function takes `GetDate()` as a parameter and although its considered a constant during the run of the query, it will be different for each and every run.

As already mentioned by GercoOnline you should try to switch around the situation so that you can write the query as `WHERE c.myField <= dbo.SomeFunction(@var1, @var2)` where @varN is 'constant' for the duration of the query (e.g. `GetDate()` will work, `NewId()` won't nor will the value of a column).

Once you get to that point, the Query Optimizer will be able to use the index on `c.myField`to get its results much more quickly. 'Inverting' the function might be a bit of a challenge as it seems that a range of input-dates might result in the same result (age). As such I think it would be better to create two functions, one that calculates the lower-date that will result in a given age, and an upper-date that will result the same given age. You'll need to adapt your query according to the requirements. If you want to have all customers aged 66 then it would look something like :

```
WHERE c.date_of_birth BETWEEN dbo.mefn_GetMinBirthDate(GETDATE(),'YEAR', 66) AND dbo.mefn_GetMaxBirthDate(GETDATE(),'YEAR', 66)
```

while if you rather need those older than 66 it would be :

```
WHERE c.date_of_birth < dbo.mefn_GetMinBirthDate(GETDATE(),'YEAR', 66)
```

or those younger than 66

```
WHERE c.date_of_birth > dbo.mefn_GetMaxBirthDate(GETDATE(),'YEAR', 66)
```